# How to tar a branch of file tree?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I currently have some files and directories at this path:
/var/tmp/mydir/

I want to tar the whole path, excluding any other content in 'var' and 'tmp'.
Example:

```
$ ls /var
tmp
dir1 *(exclude)*
file1 *(exclude)*

$ ls /var/tmp
mydir
dir2 *(exclude)*
file2 *(exclude)*

$ ls /var/tmp/mydir
tarme1
tarme2
tarme3
```

In this case, I want to tar the directory tree /var/tmp/mydir and the content of 'mydir'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tar -cf <archive_name>.tar /var/tmp/mydir` which will give you what you need.

Use `man tar` to get more help (should be quite easy to understand).

If you want to modify your path some other way consider using `-C` switch. From `man`:

```
 -C, --directory DIR
       change to directory DIR
```

Answer (score -1):

Do

```
tar -c --recursion --file backup.tar tmp/mydir
```

and

```
 tar -tvf backup.tar
```

gives me :

```
drwxrwxr-x ssam/ssam         0 2016-05-02 12:02 tmp/mydir/
-rw-rw-r-- ssam/ssam         0 2016-05-02 12:02 tmp/mydir/tarme3
-rw-rw-r-- ssam/ssam         0 2016-05-02 12:02 tmp/mydir/tarme1
-rw-rw-r-- ssam/ssam         0 2016-05-02 12:02 tmp/mydir/tarme2
```

which is what you need. You can extract/restore it using

```
tar -xf backup.tar -C /var
```

Remember this will **overwrite** the files in mydir